# Python: Reading numbers from file, put them in a list and add them, how to solve it?

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror

I want to read a file, which contains 3 numbers; separated via space, and save the numbers into a list and add the elements of the list and print the sum in Python. But I receive the following error code for the line "sum +=num[i]": *"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'"*

I know what is the problem, but couldn't solve it. Could you please help me, what to do?!

```
#read file and add the 3 numbers from the file

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as num_file:
    num = []
    for i in num_file:
        i = i.split()
        if i:
            i = [int(j) for j in i ]
            num.append(i)
print("The numbers: ")
print(num)
num_file.close()

print ("Type + if you want to add the numbers!")
add = (input())

if add == "+":
    sum = 0
    for i in range (0,3):
        **sum +=num[i]**
    print(sum)
else:
    print ("Unknown character")
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors aside, there *is* a built in method to find the sum of all the numbers in a list, `sum()`:

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as num_file:
    num = [int(n) for n in num_file.read().split() if n.isdigit()]

print("The numbers:")
print(num)

print ("Type + if you want to add the numbers!")
add = (input())

if add == "+":
    print(sum(num))
else:
    print("Unknown character")
```

Note: it is better to use a context manager rather than opening and closing a file.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as num_file:
    num = []
    for i in num_file:          # i is one line of the file
        i = i.split()           # the line is split at spaces into a list
        if i:                   # if anything is in the list
            i = [int(j) for j in i ]  # now i is a list of integers
            num.append(i)       # you add the list of integers to num
print("The numbers: ")
```

So each element of `num` is a list of integers.

To add them:

```
k = 0
for inner_list in num:
    for number in inner_list:
        k += number
```

and you are done. Unsing better names for your *variables* helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains only numbers then,a simple approach would be:

```
 with open("text.txt",'r') as f:
        a=f.read()
        l1=a.split(' ')
        print(l1)
    sum=0    
    for i in l1:
        try:
            sum+=int(i)
        except:
            print("not a number")
    print(sum)
```

output:

```
['3', '4', '5']
12
```

Hope this helps!